getting a map window in a WPF application
I am trying to have a simple map window in my WPF application. The app runs without any error but the map does not show up. I am not sure how I can debug the issue.
my WPF xaml:
<Window
    x:Class="StructuralCalculations.WindTool.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StructuralCalculations.WindTool"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr_namespace:StructuralCalculations.MainVM"
    xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainVM />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <wv2:WebView2
            x:Name="MapBrowser"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Width="500"
            Height="300"
            />
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Text="Project:" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ProjectName}" />
            <TextBlock
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Text="Job Number:" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding JobNumber}" />
            <TextBlock
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Text="Address:" />
            <TextBox x:Name="AddressTextBox" Text="{Binding Address}" />
            <!--<Button
                Margin="30,5,30,5"
                Click="CenterMapButton_Click"
                Content="Center Map" />-->
            <TextBlock
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Text="Nearest City:" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="CityNameTextBlock"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="{Binding Location, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <TextBlock
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Text="Wind Region:" />
            <TextBlock
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="{Binding WindRegion}" />
            <TextBlock
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Text="Elevation:" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="ElevationTextBlock"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="{Binding Elevation, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Button
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="4"
            Width="100"
            Height="50"
            Command="{Binding GenerateReportCommand}"
            Content="Report" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

my xaml.cs:
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;

namespace StructuralCalculations.WindTool
{
    //[ComVisible(true)] // Make the class visible to COM for scripting
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeWebView();


        }

        private async void InitializeWebView()
        {
            // Ensure WebView2 environment is initialized
            await MapBrowser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();

            // Enable JavaScript explicitly
            MapBrowser.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsScriptEnabled = true;



            // Attach event handlers after WebView2 is initialized
            MapBrowser.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += CoreWebView2_WebMessageReceived;
            MapBrowser.CoreWebView2.OpenDevToolsWindow(); // Open DevTools

            // Add a global error handler for JavaScript errors
            await MapBrowser.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(@"
                    window.onerror = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => {
                        console.error(`${message} at ${source}:${lineno}:${colno}`);
                    };
                ");





            // Get the path of the HTML file
            string htmlFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Shared", "map.html");

            // Check if the file exists
            if (File.Exists(htmlFilePath))
            {
                // Load the HTML file into WebView2
                MapBrowser.CoreWebView2.Navigate(htmlFilePath);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("HTML file not found: " + htmlFilePath);
            }
        }

        void CoreWebView2_WebMessageReceived(object sender, CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.WebMessageAsJson);
        }
    }
}

and my html with my API key hidden:
<!doctype html>
<!--
 @license
 Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Map</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <!--The div element for the map -->
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- prettier-ignore -->
    <script>
    (g => { var h, a, k, p = "The Google Maps JavaScript API", c = "google", l = "importLibrary", q = "__ib__", m = document, b = window; b = b[c] || (b[c] = {}); var d = b.maps || (b.maps = {}), r = new Set, e = new URLSearchParams, u = () => h || (h = new Promise(async (f, n) => { await (a = m.createElement("script")); e.set("libraries", [...r] + ""); for (k in g) e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g, t => "_" + t[0].toLowerCase()), g[k]); e.set("callback", c + ".maps." + q); a.src = `https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?` + e; d[q] = f; a.onerror = () => h = n(Error(p + " could not load.")); a.nonce = m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce || ""; m.head.append(a) })); d[l] ? console.warn(p + " only loads once. Ignoring:", g) : d[l] = (f, ...n) => r.add(f) && u().then(() => d[l](f, ...n)) })
            ({ key: "myHiddenApiKey", v: "weekly" });</script>
</body>
</html>

This is what I get when I run the application:

The devtool does not give any error.

please try the html directly first and see if there is any error, I don't see anything from WebView would screw this up

good point. When I open the html directly, it shows only the "my google maps demo" and nothing else. What could be wrong with the html. My account is paid. Is there any thing specific in the account that I am missing?

open dev tool and check if there is any request call and their responses. Or you can try their elaborate example instead of the minified one

I just look at their example and it seems that your minified js code is just for importing the library. Add the script to actually render the map after it:
<script>
    let map;

    async function initMap() {
        const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");

        map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8,
        });
    }

    initMap();
</script>

